# ZeroMQ SUB never receives messages

Tags: c++, zeromq

I am having trouble with a **`PUB/SUB`** in ZeroMQ.

After connecting everything, publisher publishes all messages ( socket's send message returns `true` ) but the `SUB` never receives them and blocks forever on `.recv()` function.

Here is the code I am using:

```
void startPublisher()
{
    zmq::context_t zmq_context(1);
    zmq::socket_t zmq_socket(zmq_context, ZMQ_PUB);
    zmq_socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:58951");

    zmq::message_t msg(3);
    memcpy(msg.data(), "abc", 3);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        zmq_socket.send(msg); // <-- always true
}

void startSubscriber()
{
    zmq::context_t zmq_context(1);
    zmq::socket_t zmq_socket(zmq_context, ZMQ_SUB);

    zmq_socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:58951");
    zmq_socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0); // allow all messages

    zmq::message_t msg(3);
    zmq_socket.recv(&msg); // <-- blocks forever (message never received?)
}
```

Please note that I am runing these 2 functions in two different threads, starting `SUB` thread first, waiting for some time and then starting publisher thread ( also tried other way around with publisher sending messages in an endless-loop, but didn't work ).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The subscriber must run first as part of the documentation/example and then the publisher. Add a delay between the start of the subscriber thread and the start of the publisher thread see if that makes a difference. You can add some proper synchronisation after. Set your bind like this as well please: "tcp://*:58951"

Comment: Hi, I just managed to solve this problem... This is called "slow joiner" and is described [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) in detail. In short: it takes some time for the TCP handshake to finish, thus establishing the connection. But you were absolutly right.

Comment: This could be solved by providing a suitable sync mechansicm between the start of the sub and pub.

Comment: There are more tasks under the hood of the `.context( nIoThreads )` instance, than just the noted TCP-related ones. One ought read the API, and about proper releasing of resources ( termination of sockets and context instance ), why one ought always setup a preventive value of a `.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 )` for each socket instances. Worth reading, if one is serious into going distributed. +Not all ZeroMQ versions operate the same way the topic-filtering, so if one sides subscribes to something, the filtering may take place on the PUB-side, for which even more ***"temportisation***" needed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example, the following code works for me.
The problem is that the PUB / SUB pattern is a slow joiner, meaning you need to wait a while after binding the PUB socket and before sending any message.

```
#include <thread>
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
void startPublisher()
{
    zmq::context_t zmq_context(1);
    zmq::socket_t zmq_socket(zmq_context, ZMQ_PUB);
    zmq_socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:58951");
    usleep(100000); // Sending message too fast after connexion will result in dropped message
    zmq::message_t msg(3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        memcpy(msg.data(), "abc", 3);
        zmq_socket.send(msg); // <-- always true
        msg.rebuild(3);
        usleep(1); // Temporisation between message; not necessary
    }
}
volatile bool run = false;
void startSubscriber()
{
    zmq::context_t zmq_context(1);
    zmq::socket_t zmq_socket(zmq_context, ZMQ_SUB);
    zmq_socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:58951");
    std::string TOPIC = "";
    zmq_socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, TOPIC.c_str(), TOPIC.length()); // allow all messages
    zmq_socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_RCVTIMEO, 1000); // Timeout to get out of the while loop
    while(run) {
        zmq::message_t msg;
        int rc = zmq_socket.recv(&msg);  // Works fine
        if(rc) // Do no print trace when recv return from timeout
            std::cout << std::string(static_cast<char*>(msg.data()), msg.size()) << std::endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    run = true;
    std::thread t_sub(startSubscriber);
    sleep(1); // Slow joiner in ZMQ PUB/SUB pattern
    std::thread t_pub(startPublisher);
    t_pub.join();
    sleep(1);
    run = false;
    t_sub.join();
}
```

Comment: Starting with tweaking `ZMQ_RCVTIMEO` is an escape from proper designer's work. There is both an explicitly non-blocking `.recv()`-call syntax and also a `.poll()`-instrumentation, for not having a need to use ( principally bad ) practice of blocking. Professional-grade distributed-computing systems ought never block ( due to many obvious reasons - the code being totally out-of-control during the whole duration, potentially infinite, of the blocking-state etc ), so rather do not replicate any schoolbook examples, where the code-designer was easy and withing some space-limits for a few SLOCs.

Comment: Having been an RTOS-expert, this ought sound clear and sound to your ears :o)

Comment: Yes, there are way better pattern for a distributed PUB / SUB system. I just tried to emphasize the slow joiner property while staying as close as OP's example. You are absolutly right :). But for a trivial example of a threaded PUB / SUB, it seems good enough.

Comment: Might be also interested, that not only the slow-join is the problem, also the uncertainty about the topic-filter processing ( one could hardly tell in newer versions, which side is going to handle the topic-filter processing ... )